# Как заставить phpunit выводить информацию в консоль без буферизации

Tags: php, phpunit

PHP Unittest при выполнении тестов рисует аккуратные точечки для каждого теста и если тестов много делает это в несколько строк рисуя процент исполнения на каждой строке.
Что-то вроде этого:

```
Runtime:       PHP 7.3.31-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 with Xdebug 3.0.4
Configuration: /var/www/mobport/phpunit.xml.dist

...............................................................  63 / 109 ( 57%)
.............................................
```

И я видел как это работает в режиме "онлайн" то есть точечки рисуются сразу после исполнения каждого теста. Вывод не буферизуется.

На данный момент вывод у меня буферизуется и я жду 2 минуты а потом сразу отрисовка всего экрана с описанием системы, настроек всех точек и финальных ошибок если есть.

Как отключить эту буферизацию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в битриксе. Ядро битрикса активно использует ob_cache и не док конца закрывает слои кэширования. Решили проблему вот так:

```
while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
}
```

Видео-скрин: https://mpakfmtest.ru/video/unittest3.mp4